# Near text "process"; expecting "if" VHDL

Tags: vhdl

Here is my code for paralel in serial out shif register. I get error Near text "process"; expecting "if" and i cant fix this.
Here is my code

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity shiftreg is
port(
sl:in std_logic;
clk:in std_logic;
data:in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
q:out std_logic
);
end shiftreg;

architecture myarch of shiftreg is
signal q1:std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
begin
process(sl,clk,data)
begin
    if(sl='0') then
        q1<=data;
    else if(sl='1' and rising_edge(clk)) then
        q<=q1(3);
        q1(3)<=q1(2);
        q1(2)<=q1(1);
        q1(1)<=q1(0);
        q1(0)<="0";
    end if;
end process;
end myarch;
```

Comment: `elsif` . `if` after `else` is another branch. so you need to use `end if` after the statements. Saying that, you really need to read about the synchronous process, clocks, resets etc. [if else](https://vhdlwhiz.com/if-then-elsif-else/)

Comment: Thank you! I have VHDL this semester and i just started learning it. I couldnt figure this out. Im really tired xD

Comment: [Basic VHDL](https://vhdlwhiz.com/basic-vhdl-tutorials) is great

Comment: Thank you so much!